# show that $\mathbb{E}\left(B_{1}^{2 n}\right)=(2 n-1) \mathbb{E}\left(B_{1}^{2 n-2}\right) $ using Ito's calculus

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

$B$ is a brownian motion.

Let $n$ be an integer larger than 1, by applying Ito's formula to $f(t, x) = x^{2n}$ we find that :
$$
\forall t \geq 0, B_{t}^{2 n}=2 n \int_{0}^{t} B_{s}^{2 n-1} d B_{s}+n(2 n-1) \int_{0}^{t} B_{s}^{2 n-2} d s $$

since stochastic integrals have mean $0$ then by taking the expectation of both sides and using fubini's theorem we get :

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} [B_{1}^{2n}] &= n(2n-1) \mathbb{E} [\int_{0}^{1} B_{s}^{2 n-2} d s ]  \\ &=n (2n-1)  \int_{\Omega}\int_{0}^{1} B_{s}^{2 n-2} d s d \mathbb{P} = n(2n-1)\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{E}[B_s^{2n-2}] ds 
\end{align}

so somehow, we have to prove that :$n\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{E}[B_s^{2n-2}] ds =\mathbb{E}\left(B_{1}^{2 n-2}\right) $ using Ito's calculus

I tried using the expected value formula as the integral of the survival function but it led me to nowhere

how to continue ?

Comment: What do you mean by using 'Ito's calculus'? Do they ask you specifically to use Ito's lemma? I can see  two ways to solve it but it's just taking into account that $B_t \sim (0,\sqrt{t}).$ Not sure if that would work for you.

Comment: I recall that if $X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^2 \right)$, then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, we have:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X^n] =
\begin{cases}
0 \text{ if $n$ is odd}\\
\frac{\sigma^{2n}(2n)!}{2^nn!} \text{ if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: @UBM I wouldn't mind using the fact that $B_t$ is normally distributed as I've already used Ito's lemma at this point to show the recurrence relation all above.

Comment: @rapidracim: Are you allowed to use the formula that Sesame pointed out in his comment? if you can, you can solve the exercise very quickly. If not, we use the fact that $E[e^{i u B_t}] = e^{\frac{-u^2}{2t}}$  to compute $E[B_t^{2n}]= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{\frac{- x^2}{2t}}dx.$

Comment: Another way (which is shorter I think) is to use $E[e^{i u B_t}] = e^{\frac{-u^2}{2t}}$  in conjunction with the series expansion of the exponential function.

Comment: @UBM I can't use sesame's formula because I'm supposed to deduce it from what I'm trying to prove but you mentioning the series expansion made it very clear thanks.

Comment: How about the following : we have $E[B_1^{2n}] = n(2n-1)\int_0^1 E[B_s^{2n-1}] = n(2n-1)\int_0^1 s^{n-1}E[X^{2(n-1)}]ds =(2n-1)E[X^{2(n-1)}]$ where $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Denoting $f(n) = E[X^{2n}]$, we have the following recurrence formula $f(n) = (2n-1)f(n-1)$. Now show that $f(n)$ is the quantity in my previous comment.

Comment: @Sesame I already figured it out using Taylor series but this too would be okay since we're not using any previously established result, thanks.